# Shortcut to cd into the only folder in the current directory

Tags: command-line, scripts, cd-command

Suppose I'm in `~/A` and there is a single folder in `~/A` called `folder`.

What shortcut can I press to go inside `folder` without having to type `cd folder`?

The reason for this question is that in my real life example there are some elaborate folder names that are annoying to repeatedly type out whenever I want to `cd` into subdirectories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have bash completion set up (the default), this will work:

```
cd <Tab><Enter>
```